# End Date does not update for SSIS Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I choose Historical attribute as change type for `address`,`city` and `state` columns. I choose Use start and end dates to identify current and expired records option to use the start and End dates.

However, when `address` or `city` changes, it always come outs as new update and the end_date does not change. Can anyone know why it happens? Thanks!